# whats wrong with this conditional operator?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

```
protected void MakeAutoComplete(ref Control control, IListSource dListSource)
    {
        MakeAutoComplete(ref control, dListSource, false);
    }

protected void MakeAutoComplete(ref Control control, IListSource dListSource, bool isComboBox)
    {
        var curControl = (isComboBox) ? (control as ComboBox) : (control as TextBox);
        // other
    }
```

On the line of `var curControl` VS gives me error
`Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox' and 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'` I can understand the error, and I know there is no cast btw `TextBox` and `ComboBox`, but that's why I am using `var` in the first place. so what's the problem? why is it complaining?

Comment: Type of the variable declared with `var` is decided on the compilation stage not on runtime. It's not completely dynamic like in javascript. In your case compiler cannot decide, which type it will be. The closest common parent for both `ComboBox` and `Textbox` is `Control` and this is type you originally have. I suggest you use if..then..else, for the thing you are planning to do with it.

Comment: @MihailGolubev it not dynamic at all and there no reason why if else would be better than the conditional operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it's failing is because the type of the two branches is not the same. The ternary operator `? :` requires the two branches to return the same type so that is can assign the result to the left-hand side.

Though pointless, the following would be a valid assignment.

```
var curControl = (isComboBox) ? (control as Control) : (control as Control);
```

Notice, as others have pointed out, that the keyword *var* is not a dynamic type but rather a syntactic shortcut for telling the **compiler** (not run-time) to determine the type of the variable based on the right-hand expression - *at compile time, not at run time*.

---

Or, you could write something like:

```
ComboBox curControlCombo = null;
TextBox curControlText = null;

if(isComboBox)
  curControlCombo = (control as ComboBox);
else
  curControlText = (control as TextBox);
```

Comment: Why would you do the first? Surely it's just `var curControl = control as Control;`.

Comment: you're right... no point in doing that. I didn't really read the question thoroughly.

Answer (score 5):

`var` isn't a dynamic type, it's only a convenient way of telling the compiler "you figure the type out" and have it decide. It is always a *single* type though that is decided at compile time, so you won't be able to have it be "either this type or that type" at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The C# compiler needs to be able to compute the type of the conditional at compile time.  The `var` keyword simply means that the compiler will automatically pick the type for you, but it still needs to be able to compute it at compile time.

Since there is no implicit conversion between either `TextBox` or `ComboBox`, the compiler does not know which type the conditional's return type should have.

To fix this, you need to cast it to a common type:

```
var curControl = (isComboBox) ? (control as Control) : (control as Control);
```

But then, you wouldn't need the conditional ....

Answer (score 1):

This is all about the ternary operator `?:` and has nothing to do with the `var` keyword. All of these examples give the same compile-time error:

```
var curControl = (isComboBox) ? (control as ComboBox) : (control as TextBox);
Control curControl = (isComboBox) ? (control as ComboBox) : (control as TextBox);
object curControl = (isComboBox) ? (control as ComboBox) : (control as TextBox);
dynamic curControl = (isComboBox) ? (control as ComboBox) : (control as TextBox);
Whatever curControl = (isComboBox) ? (control as ComboBox) : (control as TextBox);
```

You also get the error if you say e.g.:

```
((isComboBox) ? (control as ComboBox) : (control as TextBox)).ToString();
```

or anything similar. The `?:` operator needs to find a common type of the two arguments on either side of the colon `:`. So the types must be the same, or one of the types must be convertible to the other type (for example the other type can be a base class of it).

**But what are you trying to achieve?** The standard way to use the `as` keyword goes like this:

```
var comboBoxControl = control as ComboBox;
if (comboBoxControl != null)
{
  // great, it's a ComboBox. Do all kinds of things special for ComboBox
  // by using the comboBoxControl variable
}
// here you can do things general to all controls
// by using the original variable control
```

In the above example, `control` has *compile-time type* `Control`, and `comboBoxControl` has *compile-time type* `ComboBox`.

The run-time types are something else. The run-time type of `control` could be null, `Control` (it is not an `abstract` class!), or any class deriving from `Control`. Similarly with `comboBoxControl`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be best answered by asking what the type of `curControl` might be after your statement has executed. The only thing we can say is that candidates share a common type `System.Windows.Forms.Control`. Because c# is (mainly) statically typed, the compiler needs to resolve `curControl`'s type at compile-time. `var` does not imply dynamic typing. It is directly equivalent to stating an explicit type, but is instead inferred by the compiler (*at compile-time*). At the moment, your code is ambiguous, so the compiler complains.